# Azure Automation Runbook Workflow looses AzContext

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook, powershell-workflow

I have written the following runbook workflow, but from time to time I see the error when it try's to start or stop a VM:

> Start-AzVM : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your
> Azure credentials.
> At StartStopVmByTag:46 char:46
> +
> + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzVM], ArgumentException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StartAzureVMCommand

I have tried passing the $azContext variable in, but I still get this issue, how can I further investigate?

```
workflow StartStopVmByTag {
    $connectionName = "AzRunAsConnection2042";

    try {
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

        Write-Output "Logging in to Azure..."
        $null = Add-AzAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
    }
    catch {

        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection) {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        }
        else {
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }

    [DateTime]$now = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'GMT Standard Time')
    $startTag = 'Start Schedule'

    Write-Output "*** $now - Runbook Started  ***"

    # Get Subscriptions
    $Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

    ForEach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
        $azContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id

        # Get all VM's with a Start or Stop Schedule
        Write-Output "$($Subscription.Name): Getting VM's..."
        [Array]$taggedVms = Get-AzResource -TagName $startTag -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
        $taggedVms = $taggedVms | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique

        # For each VM, check if start schedule is valid for now
        Foreach -Parallel ($taggedVm in $taggedVms) {
            Write-Output "$($Subscription.Name): Found Tagged VM: $($taggedVm.Name), $($startTag): $($taggedVm.Tags.$startTag -replace '\s', '')"
            $WORKFLOW:null = Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $taggedVm.ResourceGroupName -Name $taggedVm.Name -DefaultProfile $azContext -NoWait
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line did the error happen? Could you reduce your code to make it a minimal reproducible code snippet?

Comment: I have minimised the code. I continue to be able to reproduce the error when running as a runbook in Azure Automation, but have never been able to reproduce it when running it on my local machine. The error is sometimes happens when it is running Start-AzVM

Comment: @JoyWang Dud you have a chance to look at the minimal reproducible code to see if you could work out what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue for a while, and I've tried dozens of different workarounds and nothing has worked. I finally resolved it with these registry settings that force .NET applications to use TLS 1.2. I find it very strange that this solution works, but possibly because the TLS 1.2 set as part of any parent task doesn't get passed on to the job.

They probably aren't all required, but it seems to be a best practice these days anyway.

```
set-itemproperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727" -name SystemDefaultTlsVersions -value 1 -Type DWord
set-itemproperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319" -name SchUseStrongCrypto -value 1 -Type DWord
set-itemproperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727" -name SystemDefaultTlsVersions -value 1 -Type DWord
set-itemproperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319" -name SchUseStrongCrypto -value 1 -Type DWord
```